# Text dexcribing my military service - not sure if correct, grammar-wise

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I could use some help :) I know that you don't proofread, but I don't know where to ask.

I had been recruited to the Military on the 20th of October, 2013. As a combat service supporter in the Teleprocessing Corps, I had been through two months of boot camp, and after I'd finished the training, I was stationed in the Ranger's unit teleprocessing battalion, serving in the southern city of ****. I've had participated in the 2014 operation *** *****, and after that, I joined the commander's course. And that's how I finished my military service after three years.

This is the order:
1. Joined the military.
2. Boot camp for two months.
3. finished the training
4. Stationed in Rangers and as serving there for a while.
5. Participated in an operation.
6. Joined commanding course
7. Finished my service.

No longer a soldier.

Is the grammar on this ext correct? The usage of had been and the other perfect tenses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, using past perfect sounds strange, and I would recommend just using past tense. Using past perfect helps when you have to jump back in time in the middle of describing a series of events-- for example, if you said you participated in a 2014 operation but *had been* recruited in 2013 (an example of jumping back in time when describing past events). But since you started at the beginning and are describing events in order, you don't need the past perfect.

I would say, "I was recruited.... in 2013" and "I went through two months of boot camp... and after I finished the training, I was stationed..." Also, definitely say "I participated in" not "I've had participated in" :) Just sticking to past tense will make everything easier to understand!

Comment: Thank you so much! You people and your perfect tenses.. haha. It's both fun and difficult. I feel like I have to use the perfect tenses more than often to sound like a native speaker

Comment: It might be helpful to think of past perfect as the way to talk about a flashback within a flashback. If you're already talking about the past, and you need to explain something that happened before that, you use past perfect to indicate that it's even farther in the past than everything else you're talking about, if that makes sense.